# Azure SQL dbmanager/loginmanager can create but not access database

Tags: powershell, automation, permissions, azure-sql-database

I have created a new sql account and assigned it dbmanager and loginmanager roles. It can be used to create new databases but I am not able to access the database afterwards with that user. When right clicking the new database to run a query, the login prompt apears and says that the security principal %user% can access the database under the current security context.

I am not able to alter or grant user any access to the DB now that I can't even run any queries.

The purpose here is that I have a powershell script that creates the databases and handles the automation under a spesific SQL user. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login might lacks the necessary permissions to connect to the specified database. Logins that can connect to this instance of SQL Server but do not have particular database rights inherit the guest user's permissions. This is a security feature that prevents users from connecting to databases where they do not have permissions. When the guest user does not have CONNECT permission to the identified database and the trustworthy attribute is not set, this error message appears. When the guest user does not have CONNECT authorization to the listed database, this error message appears.

You can connect to the database in one of the following ways:

- Grant the specific login access to the named database.
- Grant the CONNECT permission to the database named in the error message for the guest user.
- Enable the TRUSTWORTHY property on the database that has authenticated the user.

Please refer to the Microsoft Document for this error: [MSSQLSERVER_916](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-916-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: The admin user used to create the databases and users cant connect to the db it creates. Do I actually have to assign the admin user permission manually on the new database?